# Find collection containing the average of several collections with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Simple (not for me yet I guess) LINQ: I have a List of arrays, and I want to get a collection containing the average of each column. Something like:

```
var myCollection = new List<double[]>();
myCollection.Add(new []{1,2,3,4,5});
myCollection.Add(new []{3,4,5,6,7});
// Your answer -->     {2,3,4,5,6}
```

Comment: Jagged or actually 2-dimensional?  And which dimension is the "column"?  Better yet, provide a code sample of the array data.

Comment: OK, with the edit that *isn't* a "2 dimensional array" - it is a list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so?

```
var myCollection = new List<double[]>();
myCollection.Add(new double[]{1,2,3,4,5});
myCollection.Add(new double[]{3,4,5,6,7});

var qry = (from col in Enumerable.Range(0, myCollection.Min(arr => arr.Length))
           select myCollection.Average(arr => arr[col])).ToList();
```

---

Original answer from when the question referred to a "2 dimensional array":

How about (note - you may need to reverse `col` and `row` depending on how you choose to orient your data):

```
int[,] data = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5}};
var qry = (from col in Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(0))
           select new {
              col, avg = Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(1))
                         .Select(row => data[col, row]).Average()
           }).ToList();

foreach(var result in qry) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", result.col, result.avg);
}
```

Or if you just want the averages (not the anon-type):

```
var qry = (from col in Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(0))
           select Enumerable.Range(0, data.GetLength(1))
               .Select(row => data[col, row]).Average()).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you assuming the number of rows is known in advance?

Comment: @Amittai: No he isn't. Using `GetLength(0)` and `GetLength(1)` is because this is a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: I knew it should be simple, I didn't know about the Range method. Seems useful, 10x :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have modified the question, changing the 2 dimensional array to `List<double[]>`, another solution is:

```
var result = myCollection.Aggregate((arr1, arr2) => arr1.Zip(arr2, (x, y) => (x + y) / 2).ToArray())
```

Comment: Thanks, but I use 3.5, which doesn't have the Zip operator.